# How to create a fast query that returns an aggregate result into separate columns based on a subset of data?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Suppose I have a table that tracks purchases regarding a purchase using a coupon.

```
User Id = uid
Coupon Id = cid
Time of Purchase = created_at



uid | cid | created_at
25  1835    2016-12-06 05:40:08
25  1835    2017-01-05 05:17:00
25  4185    2016-12-09 07:01:16
27  1807    2016-11-18 04:33:32
27  1819    2016-12-19 20:09:10
28  2069    2016-11-30 01:15:37
28  2395    2016-11-14 00:09:53
28  2699    2016-11-15 03:52:57
28  7435    2016-11-25 00:39:43
28  7879    2016-11-08 17:11:00
28  7879    2016-11-08 22:37:15
28  7879    2016-11-10 21:57:57
28  7890    2016-11-11 20:32:27
```

How can I efficiently create a table that has aggregated on a column level.

```
Columns: 
uid
cid
oldest_created_at_today
oldest_created_at_week
oldest_created_at_month
oldest_created_at_year
```

I have solved this, however the time to build the entire aggregated table is the same time it takes to do the query on a specific uid. 
ie.

```
1.) SELECT * FROM special_new_view where uid = 28; 4.32sec
2.) SELECT * FROM special_new_view; 4.43sec
```

I need query 1 to be sub .1 sec and query 2 could be sub 5 seconds and be alright although I'm sure my expertise in mySQL is just lacking and it's possible to do much faster.

Please assume 10million+ rows on original table and that resulting data should be grouped by uid,cid.

edit: Changes table to view suffix. Also, query without view and just materialized tables is fine. Thanks.

edit2: Perhaps I should relabel the question to "How to create view of aggregate data where data is aggregated differently per column into one table without poor query times?"

Comment: How many CIDs there are max per UID ? is createt_at a timestamp ?

Comment: unlimited cids per uid, created_at is a timestamp yes.

Comment: In cases such as yours, where a simple lookup is slow - that's an indication of I/O problem, which means your database runs off of a slow mechanical disk that has to perform seeking. This is a clear indication of running the db on inadequate server, or unconfigured server. You can create the data model / tables to a point, but even a perfect data model will hit the limit of what's possible and that leaves you with looking for a faster server, sharding your data to multiple servers etc. In your case, with only 10m rows, I'd safely conclude you're running on default config. Am I right?

Comment: @N.B. You conclude correctly. However, I used 10m as it's a reasonable upper bound. The actual number of rows currently is ~300k. This is why I think it's not I/O but rather an ignorance in my knowledge of good SQL. I'm struggling to find a solution for a view to produce the entire aggregated data in under 10 seconds. The server I'm using isn't horrible but I can't imagine needing to use more complex architecture techniques yet given the relatively small size of the database (under 10 gigs total).

Comment: Because it's only 300k records, it means it's an I/O problem. Let me clarify a bit - if you are able to get 300 000 numbers or whatever the data is to CPU, it's going to perform operations on those numbers quickly. Because it takes longer than a second, it means your CPU is getting the data slowly. This means it's an I/O problem because it takes a while for your drive to find where the data is, to read it and send to CPU for processing.

Comment: Now, to answer your question - how to make all of this faster? Answer is always - do the least amount of work possible. You don't need to recalculate everything every time you look the view up. Why not create a statistics table which gets updated every time you insert / update / delete your tables with data? Upon adding / modifying the row, perform the necessary calculation and materialize it in another table which you query for statistics. You perform work once, instead of every time you read. How's that sound? I'm not sure if you're doing it, but it's one of techniques how to get the speed.

Comment: @N.B. This doesn't provide a solution for any dynamic statistic, which is exactly what this problem seeks. The data sets are relative to the current time. oldest_purchase_day is the oldest purchase for each uid,cid composite in the subset of data with created at between `now() and now() - interval 1 day`. Adding some oldest time only on inserts would mean it could be stale when I go to look the data up.

Answer (score 0):

This is only one possibility and i am sure that there are better, but its fast. my table has a new column "oldest" that direct count from oldest to newest row per uid,cid and some Indexe. the only negativ is that you only can add new records by call. i have testet it with only 200000 rec and the result was 2 ms for a query.

**the table**

```
CREATE TABLE `purchases` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `cid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `createt_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 01:00:01',
  `oldest` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `oldest` (`oldest`,`uid`,`cid`),
  KEY `uid` (`uid`,`cid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=171144 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**the stored procedure**

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `addrec`(IN p_uid INT, IN p_cid INT, IN p_create TIMESTAMP)
BEGIN


    INSERT INTO `purchases` (uid,cid,createt_at) VALUES (p_uid,p_cid,p_create);

    SET @sort = 0;
    UPDATE `purchases` p
    SET p.oldest = @sort:= (@sort+1)
    WHERE uid=p_uid AND cid =p_cid
    ORDER BY createt_at ASC;

END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

**insert a random row**

```
call addrec((rand()*1000),rand()*100,'2001-01-01 12:00:12' - interval - rand()*1000 day);
```

**the query**

select uid,cid,createt_at from purchases 
where oldest = 1 
order by uid;

**sample output with limit**

```
mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM purchases;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|   171141 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0,01 sec)

mysql>

mysql> select uid,cid,createt_at from purchases
    -> where oldest = 1
    -> order by uid
    -> LIMIT 20;
+-----+-----+---------------------+
| uid | cid | createt_at          |
+-----+-----+---------------------+
|   0 |   1 | 2001-02-09 12:00:12 |
|   0 |   3 | 2001-06-04 12:00:12 |
|   0 |   5 | 2001-08-23 12:00:12 |
|   0 |   6 | 2001-11-16 12:00:12 |
|   0 |   7 | 2001-11-30 12:00:12 |
|   0 |   8 | 2002-01-27 12:00:12 |
|   0 |   9 | 2002-03-03 12:00:12 |
|   0 |  10 | 2002-06-06 12:00:12 |
|   0 |  12 | 2002-09-04 12:00:12 |
|   0 |  13 | 2002-09-21 12:00:12 |
|   0 |  15 | 2003-01-12 12:00:12 |
|   0 |  16 | 2003-03-05 12:00:12 |
|   0 |  17 | 2003-04-10 12:00:12 |
|   0 |  18 | 2003-06-06 12:00:12 |
|   0 |  21 | 2001-02-08 12:00:12 |
|   0 |  23 | 2001-05-29 12:00:12 |
|   0 |  27 | 2001-11-23 12:00:12 |
|   0 |  28 | 2002-02-02 12:00:12 |
|   0 |  29 | 2002-03-05 12:00:12 |
|   0 |  30 | 2002-06-09 12:00:12 |
+-----+-----+---------------------+
20 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: You answered a question just not my question. You see I need to produce a table that looks like this:

`uid|cid|oldest_within_day_from_now|oldest_within_week_from_now|oldest_within_month_from_now|oldest_within_year_from_now`

Where the 'oldest' columns are the oldest timestamp within a specific set. Approaches I tried include subselects in the select of the query as well as materializing a table in the 'from' section as well as doing a 4 table left join to the entire subset where each of the joined tables is their respective sub set. All are long query time for full set.